# Get object attribute from click event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that plot markers on different places on the google maps.

The markers gets plotted correctly on the google map. I have added a click listener on each marker so that when I click on the markers, I get their respective GPS coordinates, such as Latitude & Longitude.

But when I click on a marker, I get the following exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Latitude' of undefined

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Travels/GetTravels',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                datajson = $.parseJSON(data);
                initMap(lat, long, datajson);
                console.log('InitMap..')
            }
        });
    })


    function initMap(lat, long, datajson) {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: lat, lng: long },
            zoom: 4
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < datajson.length; i++) {

            var gMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: gCircle,
                position: { lat: datajson[i].Latitude, lng: datajson[i].Longitude },
                label: {
                    color: '#e50000',
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    fontWeight: '1000',
                    text: datajson[i].TravelName.toString()
                }
            });

            gMarker.addListener('click', function () {
                alert(datajson[i].Latitude); // I am getting undefined here..
                console.log(datajson[i].Latitude);

            })
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You should not call `$.parseJSON(data);` since jQuery already has done that for you: `data` is the parsed JSON object.

Comment: No. This is not the issue. I have removed it, but same exception.

Comment: What do you have if you add a `console.log(datajson)` before the `alert` ?

Comment: Also, `initMap(lat, long, datajson)` that can’t work – where are `lat` and `long` declared?

Comment: I am not saying it is the *only* issue, but it is an issue. So don't say "No". ;-)

Comment: Would also be useful to know what `Travels/GetTravels` outputs.

Comment: `var movers = [{"MoveCount":3,"DepartureCountryCode":"MG","Latitude":-18.766947,"Longitude":46.869107},
{"MoveCount":2,"DepartureCountryCode":"MU","Latitude":-20.348404,"Longitude":57.552152},
{"MoveCount":4,"DepartureCountryCode":"ZA","Latitude":-30.559482,"Longitude":22.937506}];` @ThomasEdwards

Comment: @Hssen : I get all the markers in json. 
I want each marker to have their own attributes.

Comment: @trincot : I am parsing it as to get a proper json object.

Comment: And when you `console.log(datajson[i])` (same spot) do you get a marker ? Or is it undefined ?

Comment: Yes @Hssen I get it.

Comment: Can you show me the output ?

Comment: The output is `undefined`

Comment: Show me the exact output of datajson and the value of i.